# gstreamer srtp Encryption for video streaming

Tags: gstreamer

I am trying to create gstreamer pipeline for video streaming with SRTP encryption. I am using a H264 encoded video for streaming. I am trying to loopback in a same machine

Server Pipeline :

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location = /home/nnk7kor/simpson.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=10 pt=96 ! 'application/x-rtp, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)1356955624' ! srtpenc key="012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

Client :

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! 'application/x-srtp,encoding-name=(string)H264,ssrc=(uint)1356955624,srtp-key=(buffer)012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789,srtp-cipher=(string)aes-128-icm,srtp-auth=(string)hmac-sha1-80' ! srtpdec ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

Currently when I use GST_DEBUG=3 level as 3, I am getting a warning

> WARN                 srtpdec
>   gstsrtpdec.c:770:request_key_with_signal: Could not get caps
>   for stream with SSRC 1356955624

Am I missing anything in the caps part.